# Changing the color in heatmap in eCharts

Tags: echarts

Is there any way to change the default colors in a **calendar-based heatmap**? The default heatmap runs from shades of '*yellow*' to '*red*', based on the value. I want to change the colors so that the color runs from '*red*' to '*green*'.

This is the default color scheme
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the propriety "[inRange](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#visualMap-continuous.inRange)" you can change the color variation of the values.

```
function getVirtulData(year) {
    year = year || '2017';
    var date = +echarts.number.parseDate(year + '-01-01');
    var end = +echarts.number.parseDate(year + '-12-31');
    var dayTime = 3600 * 24 * 1000;
    var data = [];
    for (var time = date; time <= end; time += dayTime) {
        data.push([
            echarts.format.formatTime('yyyy-MM-dd', time),
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
        ]);
    }
    return data;
}

option = {
    visualMap: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        inRange : {   
            color: ['#DD2000', '#009000' ] //From smaller to bigger value ->
        }
    },
    calendar: {
        range: '2017'
    },
    series: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        coordinateSystem: 'calendar',
        data: getVirtulData(2017)
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to set breakpoints for the colors? Pieces set specific brackets, but I'd like to have a gradient red-green where it starts to turn green only after a certain number.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use in visualMap

```
  pieces: [
    {min: 0, max: 0.5, color: 'red'},        
    {min: 0.5, max: 1, color: 'green'},        
    ],
```

to customize even more